# Lowercase in SQLite for Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm now getting problem about how to convert capitalize word to lowercase in SQLite for Android.

```
public Cursor fetchFunctions(String searchword) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor =
        mDb.query(true, FUNCTIONS_TABLE, new String[] {
                FUNS_WORD, FUNS_BODY}, FUNS_WORD + "='" + searchword + "'", null,
                null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

I want to conver like **LOWER(FUNS_WORD) + "='" + searchword + "'"** unfortunately, getting syntax error. What I want is I want to convert all of data in **FUNS_WORD** to **lowercase** type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use [rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

```
public Cursor fetchFunctions(String searchword) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor =
        mDb.rawQuery("SELECT FUNS_WORD, FUNS_BODY FROM FUNCTIONS_TABLE WHERE LOWER(FUNS_WORD) = '" + searchword + "'", null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

Comment: Probably it's gonna be correct answer. By the way, how's different my coding and rawQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LIKE keyword in place of =. The LIKE keyword is case insensitive and can be used in your case without % sign.

Comment: I don't need to use LIKE because only one record needed to return.

Comment: @ppshein `LIKE` without `%` is (_almost_) same as `=`, just `LIKE` is case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

There is a SQL injection vulnerably in the query `'" + searchword + "'`. This could allow an attacker to compromise the database.

Cursors should be wrapped in try/finally blocks to ensure they are always closed upon completion.

```
public Cursor fetchFunctions(String searchword) throws SQLException {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
      cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT FUNS_WORD, FUNS_BODY FROM FUNCTIONS_TABLE WHERE LOWER(FUNS_WORD) = ?", new String[] { searchword });
      if (cursor != null) {
          cursor.moveToFirst();
      }
    } finally {
      if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
      }
    }
    return cursor;
}
```